# I can't mount my another drive in Google Colab

Tags: google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

I tried to mount my drive in Google Colab, but, I can't do it because of credential error.

I want to mount another drive different from the one I am using in Google Colab.

The following is my commands.

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

The following is the part of question.

```
MessageError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-d5df0069828e> in <module>()
      1 from google.colab import drive
----> 2 drive.mount('/content/drive')

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/colab/drive.py in mount(mountpoint, 
force_remount, timeout_ms, use_metadata_server)
    111       timeout_ms=timeout_ms,
    112       use_metadata_server=use_metadata_server,
--> 113       ephemeral=ephemeral)
    114 
    115 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/colab/drive.py in _mount(mountpoint, 
force_remount, timeout_ms, use_metadata_server, ephemeral)
    134   if ephemeral:
    135     _message.blocking_request(
--> 136         'request_auth', request={'authType': 'dfs_ephemeral'}, timeout_sec=None)
    137 
    138   mountpoint = _os.path.expanduser(mountpoint)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/colab/_message.py in 
blocking_request(request_type, request, timeout_sec, parent)
    173   request_id = send_request(
    174       request_type, request, parent=parent, expect_reply=True)
--> 175   return read_reply_from_input(request_id, timeout_sec)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/colab/_message.py in 
read_reply_from_input(message_id, timeout_sec)
    104         reply.get('colab_msg_id') == message_id):
    105       if 'error' in reply:
--> 106         raise MessageError(reply['error'])
    107       return reply.get('data', None)
    108 

MessageError: Error: credential propagation was unsuccessful
```

I could mount another drive yesterday to do the same method.

What is the solution?

Comment: This problem is happened when I used Colab Pro+ account.
When I use free Colab Account, I can mount another drive.
So, I think this problem is caused by Colab Pro+.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update:**
From Mars 30, 2022, my old solution isn't working! I find another solution (Phillip's solution) that is working now.

**Phillip's Solution:**

This solution is based on [Phillip's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71696254/8961642). You can follow his post for more information.

Follow these steps:

1. Run the below code:

```
!sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:alessandro-strada/ppa 2>&1 > /dev/null
!sudo apt-get update -qq 2>&1 > /dev/null
!sudo apt -y install -qq google-drive-ocamlfuse 2>&1 > /dev/null
!google-drive-ocamlfuse
```

2. From the previous step, you get an error like this. Click on the link that locates in the previous error message and authenticate your account.

> Failure("Error opening
> URL:https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=... ")

3. Run the below code:

```
!sudo apt-get install -qq w3m # to act as web browser 
!xdg-settings set default-web-browser w3m.desktop # to set default browser
%cd /content
!mkdir drive
%cd drive
!mkdir MyDrive
%cd ..
%cd ..
!google-drive-ocamlfuse /content/drive/MyDrive
```

You must get this message:

> Access token retrieved correctly.

**My Old Solution**

```
!apt-get install -y -qq software-properties-common python-software-properties module-init-tools
!add-apt-repository -y ppa:alessandro-strada/ppa 2>&1 > /dev/null
!apt-get update -qq 2>&1 > /dev/null
!apt-get -y install -qq google-drive-ocamlfuse fuse
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
creds = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
import getpass
!google-drive-ocamlfuse -headless -id={creds.client_id} -secret={creds.client_secret} < /dev/null 2>&1 | grep URL
vcode = getpass.getpass()
!echo {vcode} | google-drive-ocamlfuse -headless -id={creds.client_id} -secret={creds.client_secret}
%cd /content
!mkdir drive
%cd drive
!mkdir MyDrive
%cd ..
%cd ..
!google-drive-ocamlfuse /content/drive/MyDrive
```

Comment: Thank you for solving!
I have confirmed that it works properly.

Answer (score 12):

I solved this problem with [this link](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/2399). The following is the correct code:

```
from google.colab import drive  
drive._mount('/content/drive')
```

Here is the screenshot of the code:

[image: The screenshot of the solution]

Comment: It worked until yesterday. I got
          2 
          3 from google.colab import drive
    ----> 4 drive._mount('/content/drive')
          5 
          6 # !apt-get -qq install -y libsm6 libxext6 && pip install -q -U opencv-python
    
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/colab/drive.py in _mount(mountpoint, force_remount, timeout_ms, use_metadata_server, ephemeral)
        295     elif case == 5 and not use_metadata_server:
    --> 296       raise ValueError('mount failed: invalid oauth code')
    ValueError: mount failed: invalid oauth code

Comment: Now, this solution is not working.

Comment: Not working anymore

Comment: anyone tried this recently, it seemed to hang at sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:alessandro-strada/ppa

Answer (score 6):

As of now (26th January 2022), you can not mount another drive with different goggle account in Colab with drive.mount() or drive._mount(). Previously it could be done.

Now, You may use [gdrive package](https://github.com/prasmussen/gdrive) instead. Check my detailed answer in  [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70860459/8434756)

Answer (score 1):

I have a workaround, you could share folder from one drive account to another and after that you should create [shortcut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDhvZ.png). After that use regular mount

Answer (score 0):

Just copy and paste the code given below: -

```
#Connect Google Drive
from google.colab import drive
drive._mount('/content/drive')
```

Answer (score 0):

Login in chrome with the user that you want to connect to drive, don't select another account and It works for me.