# Google Colab drive mount (with underscore) is not working

Tags: python-3.x, runtime-error, google-colaboratory

Until yesterday (20 Jan) I could connect to another google drive account (using drive._mount), but when I tried this today, google colab showed me this error:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive._mount('/content/drive/')

    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/colab/drive.py in _mount(mountpoint, force_remount, timeout_ms, use_metadata_server, ephemeral)
    294       wrote_to_fifo = True
    295     elif case == 5 and not use_metadata_server:
--> 296       raise ValueError('mount failed: invalid oauth code')
    297     elif case == 6:
    298       # Terminate the DriveFS binary before killing bash.

ValueError: mount failed: invalid oauth code
```

Strange thing is that error tells me "invalid oauth code", but not let me connect to google page and copy the code!

And I set use_metadata_server=True but this time, new error appeares:

```
    from google.colab import drive
    drive._mount('/content/drive/', use_metadata_server=True)
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-42a561ce7057> in <module>()
      1 from google.colab import drive
----> 2 drive._mount('/content/drive/', use_metadata_server=True)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/colab/drive.py in _mount(mountpoint, force_remount, timeout_ms, use_metadata_server, ephemeral)
    285             ': timeout during initial read of root folder; for more info: '
    286             'https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html#drive-timeout')
--> 287       raise ValueError('mount failed' + extra_reason)
    288     elif case == 2:
    289       # Not already authorized, so do the authorization dance.

ValueError: mount failed
```

Also I used drive.mount but showed pop-up and ask me to enter another account credentials. When I enter it, this error appears:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive/')

MessageError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-91874b305a32> in <module>()
      1 from google.colab import drive
----> 2 drive.mount('/content/drive/')

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/colab/_message.py in read_reply_from_input(message_id, timeout_sec)
    104         reply.get('colab_msg_id') == message_id):
    105       if 'error' in reply:
--> 106         raise MessageError(reply['error'])
    107       return reply.get('data', None)
    108 

MessageError: Error: credential propagation was unsuccessful
```

I think this is new policy. Is there an solution?

Comment: Yesterday I was using Colab all day long and I think they pushed some changes around 8PM CET, then that drive._mount(..) "exploit" stopped to work suddenly. Anyways, here we are talking about the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70791308/mounting-google-drive-on-colab

Comment: Exactly, I have no idea what's going on!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

this feature has been removed, you can now only mount a google drive from the same account of your notebook.
https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/2562#issuecomment-1017869732

Comment: Are you sure it's removed? that's not a bug?

Comment: @OmidKhalafBeigi yes, it's confirmed. In fact one of the colab mods is gathering a lot of dislikes :)

Answer (score 7):

for the moment the only solution that is working right now is[rom this similar question but two months ago:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69819761/i-cant-mount-my-another-drive-in-google-colab/70797774#70797774)

```
!apt-get install -y -qq software-properties-common python-software-properties module-init-tools
!add-apt-repository -y ppa:alessandro-strada/ppa 2>&1 > /dev/null
!apt-get update -qq 2>&1 > /dev/null
!apt-get -y install -qq google-drive-ocamlfuse fuse
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
creds = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
import getpass
!google-drive-ocamlfuse -headless -id={creds.client_id} -secret={creds.client_secret} < /dev/null 2>&1 | grep URL
vcode = getpass.getpass()
!echo {vcode} | google-drive-ocamlfuse -headless -id={creds.client_id} -secret={creds.client_secret}
%cd /content
!mkdir drive
%cd drive
!mkdir MyDrive
%cd ..
%cd ..
!google-drive-ocamlfuse /content/drive/MyDrive
```

Let's hope for the normal way `drive.mount` to be fixed soon!

Answer (score 3):

As @user1086010 mentioned this feature has been removed. I am using "gdrive" package instead. Run the following notebook code block for installing gdrive packhage

```
import os

com_wget = "sudo wget " +"https://github.com/prasmussen/gdrive/releases/download/2.1.1/gdrive_2.1.1_linux_386.tar.gz"
com_unzip = "sudo tar -xzf gdrive_2.1.1_linux_386.tar.gz"
com_permission = "sudo chmod +x gdrive"
com_install_executor = "sudo install gdrive /usr/local/bin/gdrive"

os.system(com_wget)
os.system(com_unzip)
os.system(com_permission)
os.system(com_install_executor)
```

then connect your drive with "gdrive list":

```
!sudo gdrive list
```

You can download your files with:

```
!gdrive download <gdrive_file_id>
```

you can upload with:

```
!gdrive upload <path_to_file>
```

or for directory:

```
!gdrive upload -r <path_to_dir>
```

You can upload a file to a specific gdrive folder using:

```
!gdrive upload --parent <gdrive_folder_id> <path_to_file>
```

For removing the authentication token run the following command:

```
!rm -rf ~/.gdrive/token_*.json
```

Check this link for reference use cases and documentation of the package:
[gdrive package link](https://github.com/prasmussen/gdrive/)

Answer (score 1):

Alright, until this problem get solved, I did this trick for my project:
I shared which files I need (like datasets) with my other accounts. For this, you should:

1. Go to your google drive (where your file is stored) then right-click on it and choose "Share"
2. Click on "Change to anyone with the link"
3. Copy link and open it in new window
4. In top-right side, click on your google accounts list and select which one you need
5. At the opened window, in top-right side click on "Add shortcut to Drive" and choose location where you want to save file in it
6. Your file now is accessible in account you did choose

Answer (score 0):

I can't upload or download files from my gdrive to my colab (same account, worked 48 hours ago).

Underscore or not.

Yes, if you share a file to anyone on the internet and use !gdown you can load a file from your gdrive to colab but good luck saving it on your gdrive after.

Pydrive only lets you upload tiny kiddie files.

You had never guessed the world's biggest IT company could be behind his kindergarden show.

Sad that they are too big to fail.
They got no real competition.

Comment: What's error when you try to upload or download files? I can use mount (without underscore) and it's okay...

Answer (score 0):

Like it or not for now we can not mount another drive from colab. So forget **drive._mount** as it is not working (**._mount**)

SO the only solution that is working is to copy your folder from your other drive to your current drive (The account you are login in to in the colab) and use **drive.mount** (and not **drive._mount**)

OR

just login into colab with your account that has the folder/directory you want to mount to in your drive

Answer (score 0):

By selecting all the features that Google Drive for desktop can access, it will work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: "By selecting all the features" : that worked for me. Thank you.